# Coldfusion "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" decryption in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, coldfusion, openssl

I need to decrypt text encrypted using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding scheme. The encrypted text I got was generated using Coldfusion.

CFML example below:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr bgcolor="c0c0c0">
        <th>Decrypted string</th>
    <th>3DESKey</th>
    </tr>
        <cfset variables.algorithm ="AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding">
        <cfset variables.seed ="C610297CE8570750">
        <cfset variables.password = "Vza0O49SHpIe/mR4+4jHXhApmKhEyl5O2nzzDxVNQbo=">
        <cfset variables.decryptedString = Decrypt(variables.password, generate3DesKey("#variables.seed#"), "#variables.algorithm#", "Base64")>
        <cfoutput>
        <tr>
            <td>#variables.decryptedString#</td>
        <td><cfoutput>#generate3DesKey("variables.seed")#</cfoutput></td>
        </tr>
        </cfoutput>
</table>
```

Output is:

```
Decrypted String: Name322big563
3DESKey: QzYxMDI5N0NFODU3MDc1MA==
```

I tried with ruby:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

string = "Vza0O49SHpIe/mR4+4jHXhApmKhEyl5O2nzzDxVNQbo="

def decrypt(cpass)
  des = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
  des.decrypt
  des.key = 'C610297CE8570750'
  return des.update(Base64.decode64(cpass)) + des.final
end

decrypted = decrypt(string)

puts "decrypted string: #{decrypted}"
```

I get `key length too short (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)`
The problem is I don't know the key but only the seed used `C610297CE8570750`, because the key returned by the CFML script is base64 but I need a hex key.
I tried also with `OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CBC)` same error.

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
# decryption

aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CBC)
aes.decrypt
aes.padding = 1 # actually it's on by default
aes.key = "QzYxMDI5N0NFODU3MDc1MA=="
aes.iv = "C610297CE8570750"
aes.update(Base64::decode64("Vza0O49SHpIe/mR4+4jHXhApmKhEyl5O2nzzDxVNQbo="))+aes.final
```

Any idea?

EDIT:

As hinted by @Leigh, need to use `AES-128-CBC`, so I did this:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

string = "Vza0O49SHpIe/mR4+4jHXhApmKhEyl5O2nzzDxVNQbo="

def decrypt(cpass)
  des = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('AES-128-CBC')
  des.decrypt
  des.key = 'C610297CE8570750'
  return des.update(Base64.decode64(cpass)) + des.final
end

decrypted = decrypt(string)

puts "decrypted string: #{decrypted}"
```

actually seems to kinda work (...ish).

```
decrypted string: ▒▒.ϥD▒▒       ▒▒▒▒▒Name322big563
```

any idea what's still wrong?

Comment: *RE: but I need a hex key* Then convert it from base64 to hex. However, it looks there are a few other problems A) The CF code generates a 128 bit key, but the ruby code is using AES 256 bit B) The CF code is generating a *random IV*. I am not sure if you can derive it from the values.

Comment: I will look further and get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Expanded from comments)

> but I need a hex key

Then convert it from base64 to hex. In CF, you can use the [BinaryEncode() and BinaryDecode functions](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/BinaryEncode):

```
binaryEncode(binaryDecode("QzYxMDI5N0NFODU3MDc1MA==", "base64"), "hex")
```

Looks like there are a few other problems:

1. The CF code generates a 128 bit key, but the ruby code is using AES 256. It needs to use AES 128.
2. The CF code is generating a *random* IV.  The Ruby code is using a totally different `iv`. With `CBC` mode, both sides must use the same `iv` to get the expected results. ["Decrypting with the incorrect IV causes the first block of plaintext to be corrupt ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24314678/php-decrypting-aes-returns-padding-at-front-of-string/24335529#24335529), which is why your decrypted value is off. To resolve it, the Ruby code should use the same `iv` that was used to encrypt.

---

**Update:**

When CF generates the IV automatically (as it does here), it [prepends that IV to the encrypted value](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/strong-encryption-coldfusion-mx-7.html):

> When ColdFusion creates an IV automatically, it generates a secure,
>   random IV and prepends this to the encrypted data. When ColdFusion
>   decrypts the data, this IV is recovered and used. It is
>   cryptologically important that the IV varies between encryptions. This
>   is why the encrypted value changes when you repeatedly encrypt the
>   same string with an algorithm that uses an IV, like
>   DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding. Unlike the encryption key, it is not necessary
>   for the IV to be kept secret.

So the IV value can be extracted by removing the first "block" of the encrypted binary. The block size depends on the algorithm. For AES, it is 16. I do not know the exact Ruby code, but in CF you could extract the IV like so:

```
blockSize = 16;
rawBinary = binaryDecode(encryptedString, "base64");
// IV is always the first block 
ivBytes   = arraySlice(rawBinary, 1, blockSize);
// Remaining bytes are the encrypted value
dataBytes = arraySlice(rawBinary, blockSize+1, arrayLen(rawBinary)-blockSize);
```

Comment: Please take a look at my edit code to my question, the AES 128 code decrypts the data but adds some garbage before.

Comment: Did you see the link above? It is because the Ruby code is not using the same `iv` that was used to encrypt the value. When the `iv` is different, the first block is corrupted. You could probably remove the first block, but I am not sure that is reliable. The best option is to explicitly generate a *random* `iv` on the CF side, then use that same `iv` in your Ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm very much mistaken, this is a problem I encountered years ago.

[PHP Encryption Code Converted to ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808107/php-encryption-code-converted-to-coldfusion)

Comment: My take on it was they are simply trying to match the 128 bit results generated by CF - in Ruby. That said .. if they actually do need to use 256 bit in CF, BC is a good option.